# FB.Canvas.setSize and dynamic content?

Tags: facebook

I have a webpage inside the Facebook iframe canvas. I set this:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({
        appId: '112144505628023',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
    });

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
    }

    function sizeChangeCallback() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize();
    }
</script>
```

but inside the page I have a jquery `animate` that increase the height when a user click on a element. This create the scroll of the right.

How can I fix this? Is there a `FB.Canvas.autoSetSize()`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you could have easily figured out the answer yourself by looking into the official docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, the only drawback is that on your app settings you must specify a fixed height of 800px and then use:

```
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()
```

Here's more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/

But if you know when your content is going to change you should use

```
FB.Canvas.setSize()
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/